# Spring-Authentication to LDAP directory with a service account

Tags: authentication, spring-security, ldap

I'm working on an application developped on Spring and trying to make a connection with a LDAP Direcotory.
I have a service account which gives access to the LDAP Directory, but something wrong with my configuration.

- my service account : *login/password >> service/servcicepass*
- one user account registred in the LDAP directory : *login/password >>

  user1/pass1*

When i try to login with the user account on the login interface i got an error, but by typing the login/password of the service account i log in.

My **user-coontext.xml** file is :

```
> <!-- LDAP -->         <security:ldap-server
> url="ldap://192.168.1.68:389/o=digital" />        <bean
> id="ldapAuthProvider"
> class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
>       <constructor-arg>           <bean
> class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
>               <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
>               <property name="userDnPatterns">
>                   <list>
>                       <value>uid={0}</value>
>                   </list>
>               </property>             </bean>         </constructor-arg>      <constructor-arg>           <bean
> class="edu.mit.kit.userdetails.MappedLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
>               <property name="admins">
>                   <set>
>                       <!-- list admin usernames here -->
>                   </set>
>               </property>             </bean>         </constructor-arg>  </bean> 
>           <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
>       <property name="url" value="ldap://192.168.1.68:389/">      <property
> name="base" value="o=digital,ou=TechnicalAccount,ou=Comp" />  </bean>
> 
>   <bean id="ldapTemplate"
> class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">       <constructor-arg
> name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />   </bean>         <bean
> id="ldapUserInfoRepository" primary="true"
> class="edu.mit.kit.repository.impl.LdapUserInfoRepository">
>       <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />     </bean>

><!-- end LDAP -->
```

Can you help please  ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and i want to share it with you :

change the configuration and put :

> security:ldap-server url="ldap://192.168.1.68:389/o=digital"
>   manager-dn="uid=service,ou=TechnicalAccounts"
>   manager-password="servicepass" />